# Dictionary of English Dialects

Tags: phonology, pronunciation, dialects

I am working on simulating what changing the English orthography (s.t. it would be (more) transparent) would do to the reading process. A natural question that arises is: If the spelling is tailored to the phonology of one particular dialect, what happens to a speaker of a different dialect, when confronted with that spelling? For that I need a resource, which could be one of the following:

- A dictionary of words with phonetic transcriptions for at least two dialects of English
- A corpus with phonetic transcriptions for each of at least two dialects
- A corpus with transcriptions in one dialect and a dictionary of transcriptions in another
- A corpus with transcriptions in one dialect and a set of rules (:|) for getting pronunciations in that dialect to those of another

Does anybody know of any such resources?

Comment: What time period are you thinking about?

Comment: For what I've done so far, I have used CELEX and the BNC, so contemporary would be optimal, but it doesn't _really_ matter. The time periods of both dialects should be comparable though.

Comment: Would the [Freiburg English Dialect Corpus](http://www2.anglistik.uni-freiburg.de/institut/lskortmann/FRED/index.htm) suit your needs?

Comment: Wiktionary normally has a wide range of phonetic transcriptions, usually at least for British and American English.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Freiburg Corpus only has orthographic, but not phonetic transcriptions, so it doesn't help me.

I guess it's clear why I would prefer a resource put together by linguists, but I guess I'll have to scrape the transcriptions from wiktionary after all. Thanks.